# Image related issue on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, machine-learning

[image: In this what does it mean by (-0.5, 398.5,341.5, -0.5)? I am new on this sector so]

In this what does it mean by (-0.5, 398.5,341.5, -0.5)? I am new on this sector so still have a lot of lag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jupyter Notebooks use the IPython Kernel, which for convenience displays what is returned from the last expression in the cell. Here that is the `plt.axis('off')`. Therefore, look at the return value of this call in the docs [matplotlib.pyplot.axis](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axis.html) which shows that it is:

```
xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax : float. 
The axis limits.
```

Comment: So, the x-axis and y-axis both start from -0.5 rather than 0.